# Is there a way to count all open windows with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I'm wondering if it is possible to count the amount of windows open at a given time with vbscript. I already am familiar with the `shell.application` object and can count Windows Explorer instances, but I would like to count every window, minimized or maximized, no matter what it is. 
I have also thought about counting all running tasks, but I would need to somehow distinguish between background and foreground tasks for that to work.

```
function fnShellWindowsCountVB()
        dim objShell
        dim objShellWindows

        set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
        set objShellWindows = objshell.Windows

        if (not objShellWindows is nothing) then
            dim nCount
            nCount = objShellWindows.Count

            msgBox nCount
        end if

        set objShellWindows = nothing
        set objShell = nothing
end function
fnShellWindowsCountVB()

'only counts explorer.exe windows
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't with VBScript.

You have to make API calls to do anything with a window.

VB.Net can make API calls and is built into Windows like VBScript.

This is from https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/winlistexe-list-open-windows-and-their.html

It lists all open windows which you will have a few hundred of. Possibly you are only interested in *top level windows*.

EG Notepad is 5 windows. 1 x top level, 1 x Edit control window, 1 x statusbar window, and two standard windows that all program get automatically to handle entering Chinese text etc.

WinList.exe list the open windows and their child windows' Window Title, Window Class, and the EXE file

Note you must run as admin to access information about elevated windows.

```
REM WinList.bat
 REM This file compiles WinList.vb to WinList.exe
 REM WinList.exe list the open windows and their child windows' Window Title, Window Class, and the EXE file that created the window. 
 REM To use type WinList in a command prompt
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc "%~dp0\WinList.vb" /out:"%~dp0\WinList.exe" /target:exe
 Pause




 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------






'WinList.vb
 imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 
 Public Module WinList  

 Public Declare Function GetTopWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
 Public Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wCmd As Integer) As IntPtr
 Public Declare UNICODE Function GetWindowModuleFileNameW Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal WinModule As String, StringLength As Integer) As Integer
 Public Declare UNICODE Function GetWindowTextW Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
 Public Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpdwProcessId As IntPtr) As IntPtr
 Public Declare UNICODE Function GetClassNameW Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
 Public Declare Function IsWindowUnicode Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
 Public Const GW_CHILD = 5
 Public Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2

 Public Sub Main ()
        Dim WindowChain as Integer
            WindowChain = 0        
        Dim hwnd As IntPtr
        hwnd = GetTopWindow(0)
        If hwnd <> 0 Then
                            AddChildWindows(hwnd, 0)
                End If
 End Sub


 Private Sub AddChildWindows(ByVal hwndParent As IntPtr, ByVal Level As Integer) 
        Dim objWMIService As Object
        Dim colItems As Object
        Dim TempStr As String        
        Dim WT As String, CN As String, Length As Integer, hwnd As IntPtr, TID As IntPtr, PID As IntPtr, MN As String, Parenthwnd As IntPtr
        Static Order As Integer
        Static FirstTime As Integer
        Parenthwnd = hwndParent
        If Level = 0 Then
                        hwnd = hwndParent
        Else
            hwnd = GetWindow(hwndParent, GW_CHILD)
        End If
        Do While hwnd <> 0
                 WT = Space(512)
                  Length = GetWindowTextW(hwnd, WT, 508)
                  WT = Left$(WT, Length)
                  If WT = "" Then WT = Chr(171) & "No Window Text" & Chr(187)
                  CN = Space(512)
                  Length = GetClassNameW(hwnd, CN, 508)
                  CN = Left$(CN, Length)
                  If CN = "" Then CN = "Error=" & Err.LastDllError
                  MN = ""

                  TID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, PID)

        objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
        colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process where ProcessID=" & CStr(PID))
        For Each objItem in colItems        
                MN = objItem.name 
        Next                           
                Dim Unicode  as Boolean
        Unicode = IsWindowUnicode(hwnd)

                  Order = Order + 1
                If FirstTime = 0 Then
                    Console.writeline("Window Text                   " & "Class Name               " & vbTab & "Unicode" & vbtab & "HWnd" & vbTab & "ParentHWnd" & vbTab & "ProcessID" & vbTab & "ThreadID" & vbTab & "Process Name" )
                    FirstTime = 1
                End If
        TempStr = vbCrLf & Space(Level * 3) & WT 
        If 30 - len(TempStr) > -1 then
                TempStr = TempStr & space(30 - len(TempStr))
        End If
        TempStr = TempStr & " " & CN 
        If 55 - len(TempStr) > -1 then
                TempStr = TempStr & space(55 - len(TempStr))
        End If
                Console.write(TempStr  & vbtab & Unicode & vbTab & CStr(hwnd) & vbTab & CStr(Parenthwnd) & vbTab & CStr(PID) & vbTab & CStr(TID) & vbTab & MN )

                  AddChildWindows(hwnd, Level + 1)
                  hwnd = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT)
        Loop
      End Sub

 End Module
```

Comment: Thank you, I will see if I can implement this into my setup.

Comment: What are you trying to do. Its a lot easier to see if a particular window is open. https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/topmostexe-set-window-on-top-or-not.html shows searching for a particular window title.

Comment: I'm working on a Windows game project that plays like an arg, but within a user's computer. The game takes advantage of different OS functions and requires the user to solve puzzles within their system. As of right now, counting windows is just an idea for one part of the game.